# Datatables Re-adjust column width after cell update

Tags: javascript, datatable

On my `datatables` table, I can't get the column width to update after I've updated a cell with a long string.

---

I start with this (everything is fine):

[image]

---

But when I update a table cell with lots of text, the header column width doesn't update:

[image]

---

Here's the code I'm using to initialize the table:

```
    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        paging: true,
        scrollX: true,
        search: {'smart': false},
        columnDefs: [
            {className: 'last_column_td', targets: [last_col_id]}  // add class to cells of last col for easy selection
        ],
        iDisplayLength: 10,
        lengthMenu: [[10, -1], [10, "All"]],
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: ['copy', 'csv', 'excel']
    });
```

Note: `datatables` creates *two* tables when the parameter `scrollX` is set to `true` (one table for the headers, one table for the actual data / cells).

The [internet says](https://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust()) I need to call `table.columns.adjust().draw()` after updating the cell's content so the table will adjust itself, but this has not worked for me.

Any idea on how I can have the column widths update after I change cell content to a long string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was using an incorrect approach to update the cells within the table, resulting in an 'unrecognized' update to the cell values.

I was updating the `innerHTML` attribute of the cell using Jquery's [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.  But as stated on datatables' website, an initialized table will not 'recognize' a change to a cell's inner HTML as a change to the cell's *value* so functionality (such as the problem in the question) will occur, and functions such as [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell()) will not recognize the update to the value.  In short, a disconnect is created between the visible table on the page and the actual table values contained within the initialized (original) table.

To correctly update a table cell, one should first select the cell using datatable's [`cell()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cell()) or [`cells()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells()) method, followed by the `draw()` method to update the visible table with the changed values.